# Musics player stops working when the tab is tilted to landscape!

Tags: updates, music-player

I am using I ball Slide 72363G17 4GB, I just had an firmware update and after that, whenever I tilt the tab to landscape while playing music, music player stops working by showing the message "Unfortunately, Music has stopped."
Please give me a solution.
If you don't know a solution, please tell me how can I roll back the update.

Comment: Did you see if this is an issue with the firmware? What happens when rotation is locked?

Comment: @HasH_BrowN When I open music player while the device is in portrait mode, it works well.